# Custom viewpager strip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Does android provides any opportunity to customize standard PageTitleStrip or PageTabStrip?
I want to create some title like this? What view should i extend, maybe there are some best practice in this sphere?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just create your own custom view, connect it to your view pager via call to ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener and voila - you have your own page strip.

You can look at sources of [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) and PageTitleStrip itself (Android source code is freely available) to get an idea how to implement this in details

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a little late but I finally found a solution to my problem of how to customize the titlestrip. I realize this is not a very clean way of customizing the titlestrip but I couldn't find any better solution anywhere. I hope it will save some time for you guys.

First create a new class extending the PagerTitleStrip and override the constructor taking two arguments:

```
public class MyPagerTitleStrip extends PagerTitleStrip {

    public MyPagerTitleStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ((ViewManager) (this.getChildAt(2)).getParent()).removeView((TextView)this.getChildAt(2));
        ((ViewManager) (this.getChildAt(0)).getParent()).removeView((TextView)this.getChildAt(0));
    }

}
```

As you can see, I removed two textviews from the titlestrip in a hacky kind of way so be weary of this. These are the two textviews displaying the titles of the previous and next item respectively.

You may want to do something different than me so have a close look at he android PagerTitleStrip class, especially the constructor, before you change/hack anything. The constructor is probably the place where you want to add drawables etc.
Changing Views in the `protected void onLayout()` method will probably cause the view to be drawn twice which is not very good for the performance of your app (you'll see a lot of warning in your log).

In xml everything is still the same:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_pager"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <com.package.MyPagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:background="#111111"
            style="@style/viewPagerTitleStrip">
        </com.package.MyPagerTitleStrip>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```